# wireshark save capture directly to file with filter

Tags: networking, dns, logging, wireshark, network-monitoring

I am looking to have a long-term packet capture running to monitor DNS requests on my machine. I generally use wireshark for network monitoring, but since I am only interested in DNS packets, and over the longer time period, I wonder if it is possible to log the network activity directly to disk and only to save packets based on a filter (`dns && ip.src == MY.IP.ADDR.ESS`)

Does anyone know how I would achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tshark.

// Get list of interfaces

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -D
```

// Run on desired interface with -i #, where # is the number of the interface you wish to monitor.

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -i # -f "udp port 53" -w C:\DNSDump.txt
```

// If you prefer to capture the human readable output, do this instead.

```
C:\Program Files\Wireshark>tshark -i # -f "udp port 53" > C:\DNSDump.txt
```

NOTE: You'll have to run an elevated cmd to write to C, or runas admin, but you can write to other drives without doing this.
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html